Clipping a moving Rectangle within the bounds of a rounded Rectangle in QML
I am creating a custom style in QML and would like to have an indeterminate progress bar that looks like this, a rounded background with a rounded bar on the inside that moves from left to right.

The trouble I'm having is with behavior when the bar reaches the end.  Using just the clip property causes the rounded bar to become square when in contact with the edge.

Rectangle {
    id: bg
    color: "black"
    width: 120; height: 8; radius: 4; x: 100; y: 50
    clip: true
    
    Rectangle {
        id: bar
        color: "orange"
        width: 60; height: 8; radius: 4
      
        NumberAnimation on x {
            running: true
            from: -(bar.width * 1.2 )
            to: bg.width * 1.2
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            duration: 1000
        } 
    }
}

This is because clip uses the bounding rectangle of the parent object.  Fair enough.
I next tried using a MultiEffect (I'm using Qt6 so no OpacityMask) to apply to the bar, however after some experimenting I found that the masking properties of the MultiEffect do not take into account the position of the maskSource so this didn't work.
MultiEffect {
    source: bar
    anchors.fill: bar
    maskEnabled: true
    maskSource: bg
}

How can I achieve the desired behavior, ie having the bar be clipped by the background which has rounded corners?
I'm aware I can achieve a similar effect by growing and shrinking the bar's width when at the respective edges but I would like to avoid this if possible.

First point, there is OpacityMask in Qt6, but it is under Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects.
Second point, the problem is solvable with the Qt6 MultiEffect. The pain point is the maskSource must be specified slightly different than the OpacityMask equivalent with a necessary Item to create the layering.
The animation bar needs to be updated to contain both the black background and the animating bar.
[EDIT]
For improved anti-aliasing, let's put (1) enable clip and radius in the source, (2) however, turn OFF antialiasing in the maskSource.
    Rectangle {
        id: barWithBackground
        width: 120; height: 8; x: 100; y: 50; radius: 4
        clip: true
        visible: false
        color: "black"
        Rectangle {
            id: bar
            color: "orange"
            width: 60; height: 8; radius: 4
            NumberAnimation on x {
                running: true
                from: -(bar.width * 1.2 )
                to: barWithBackground.width * 1.2
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                duration: 1000
            }
        }
    }

    // OpacityMask
    // Qt5.* from QtGraphicalEffects
    // Qt6.* from Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
    // OpacityMask {
    //     source: barWithBackground
    //     anchors.fill: barWithBackground
    //     maskSource: roundedRectangleMask
    // }

    // Since Qt6.5
    MultiEffect {
        source: barWithBackground
        anchors.fill: barWithBackground
        maskEnabled: true
        maskSource: roundedRectangleMask
    }

    Item {
        id: roundedRectangleMask
        width: 120; height: 8
        layer.enabled: true
        visible: false
        Rectangle {
            color: "black"
            width: 120; height: 8; radius: 4
            antialiasing: false
        }
    }


Brilliant, this worked (with some modifications, I'll edit when the edit queue dies down).  This seems to have completely disabled antialiasing for the affected objects though, do you know off the top of your head how to re-enable it?  I couldn't find out from some quick googling

@eejakobowski I have enabled antialiasing in the source and disabled antialiasing in the maskSource. I think this improves the result.
